# Composite-id class must implement Serializable

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I'm trying to user JPA with kotlin and basicly got two classes, who should work together. I am having a problem with how I to make data class Crops serializable. I've tried adding @Serializable to Crops, but IntelliJ tells me Crops dont have a constructor. Here are the two classes:

```
@Entity
data class Crops(
    val amountOwned: Int = 0
) {

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
lateinit var user: User


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
lateinit var plant: Plant


constructor(user: User, plant: Plant) : this() {
    this.plant = plant
    this.user = user
}}


@Entity
data class User (
    @Id
    val username: String = "",

    @get: NotBlank
    val password: String = "",

    @get: NotBlank
    val salt: String = "",

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    val crops: MutableSet<Crops> = HashSet()
```

All help is appriciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you try to use MapsId instead of Id in the class Crops?

Comment: @SimonMartinelly Thanks, but get AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity

Comment: As an interim solution I've added   @Id val id: Int.

Comment: I would say that you need an IdClass for Crops. Like if you have a composite key. Have you tried that?

Comment: IdClass worked! Thank you!

Comment: Great. If you don't mind I will add this as the answer. I would appreciate it if you wil accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a IdClass for Crops because JPA requires to have a single class for methods like EntityManager.find()

```
data class CropsId (val username: String = "")
```

Then use it with @IdClass

```
@IdClass(CropsPK::class)
@Entity
data class Crops(
    val amountOwned: Int = 0
) {

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
lateinit var user: User


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
lateinit var plant: Plant


constructor(user: User, plant: Plant) : this() {
    this.plant = plant
    this.user = user
}}
```